# Find the number of ways to get from one point on a cartesian place to another

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to get from point (0, 0) to point (15, 17). You can move (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1) but you have to move by (1, 1) exactly 6 times.

Comment: VERY much a duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108748/paths-on-a-grid-and-how-many

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number Of Distinct Paths In A Rectangular Grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498585/number-of-distinct-paths-in-a-rectangular-grid)

Comment: I saw it, mine is a bit different and I cant manage to solve it.

Comment: How would I take into consideration that I can use (1,1) and I use it 6 times?

Comment: Ignore it and change the end point to $(9,11)$ instead.

Comment: Then it would be 20!/(9!*11!), right? What do I do about the remaining 6 (1,1) now?

Comment: @AndrewChin But the (1,1) moves do not all have to be made last. They can be mixed in with the other moves. So ${20\choose9}$ is far too small.

Comment: @Андрей You can develop a formula by looking at a 2x2 grid and 3x3 grid. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Андрей Hello? Could you answer my question, please?

Comment: Sorry, yes I found out about the formula

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make 6 NE moves, 9 E moves and 11 N moves. A total of 26 moves and you can make them in any order, but each order gives a different valid path, so the answer is just $$\frac{26!}{11!9!6!}$$

Comment: I cannot see why this should be wrong? I think it looks correct.

Comment: Someone who downvoted should say what they think is wrong, so we can discuss it.

Comment: I think people are downvoting not because the answer is incorrect, but rather because answering PSQs is considered to be in bad taste. (To be clear, I didn't downvote)